# List.Add vs List.Insert

Tags: c#

What is the difference between the Add and Insert operations of List?.

```
List<Tuple<int,string>> samplelinq = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
```

Here I want one tuple to list. Shall I use add or insert.

Comment: add just appends in the collection, while insert you can tell at which particular location/index to add

Comment: Have you tried looking up the documentation? (And those are not linq functions but of `List<T>`

Comment: _"Shall I use add or insert"_ - Well, are you adding or inserting?

Comment: @John I am asking the same that you asking what is the difference between both of them

Comment: I've added an answer. FWIW the docs are _always_ a good starting place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add will always insert at the end of the array, while Insert allows you to select an index. 
I typically prefer Add when I'm accumulating things. However if the order of the structure is important and it needs to mutate/change (for example if the new element NEEDS to be at position 4), then Insert is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately the difference between [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=netframework-4.7.2) is explained by the documentation:

**Add**

> Adds an object to the end of the List.

Signature:

```
public void Add (T item);
```

**Insert**

> Inserts an element into the List at the specified index.

Signature:

```
public void Insert (int index, T item);
```

**Summary**

So the answer to your question as to which is better, depends entirely on what you are trying to achieve. If you're simply trying to add an item to end of a list, use `Add`.